# Nice looking rendering of "summaryDefault" objects in R/Knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, xtable, kable

I am trying to make some reports with Rmarkdown, and one of the things I would like to display in nice, formatted text is results of the summaryDefault type object. I have tried using Kable and XTables, but neither seems to be up to the task.

With Kable, I get this:

```
> kable(summary(as.vector(matrix)))
Error in provideDimnames(x, sep = sep, base = base) : 
  'dimnames' applied to non-array
```

I found a [thread](https://github.com/yihui/printr/issues/21) saying that this was an issue that had been fixed, but I am using Knitr 1.17, which afik is the current version.

I have also tried the Xtable package, but:

```
> xtable(summary(as.vector(matrix)))
Error in xtable.table(summary(as.vector(mads_exons))) : 
  xtable.table is not implemented for tables of > 2 dimensions
```

Is it possible to do this with either of these packages, or some other package that I'm not aware of?

Comment: `library(dplyr); 1:10 %>% summary() %>% as.matrix() %>% t() %>% knitr::kable()` works.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Put it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: * I had to leave out the transpose, to make it work